# How do I extract the info in a table from azure to a listview in adroid studio?

Tags: azure, android-studio, android-listview

I have a register page that takes the information I put in in a table in azure. now I want to set up a page that displayes this table as a listview in android studio. how do I get an array of all the info that I have in azure? sorry if question is unclear im new to coding. and if it makes any difference one of the items in the table is a picture and the others are plain text

Comment: A register page that the details go to a table in Azure? Is the table in Azure Table Storage? Azure SQL? Need a bit more info on what you're trying to do.

Comment: im using azure sql

Answer (score 0):

welcome to the world of programming. You're about to enter a sometimes frustrating yet very rewarding world.

What you're building is a distributed system, where one part of your system(your server, where your database table lays) is physically separated from your other part(your client, or your android device).
To have them communicate together there are 2 options:
A Socket connection, which is expensive and for your usage an overkill. It is mostly used for chatting application, because it allows bi-directionaly communication (server and client can send signals to each other at any time).
Another, the common way, is to build a REST API. The commmunication between the server and the client mostly happen through HTTP. There are many tutorials on this on the internet.
Developers that focus on building the server part are called Backend Developers. As you probably guessed, the part of the system that is capable of serving other clients with data is called the "backend", while everything that receives and displays the data is called the "frontend". You'll mostly hear frontend in combination with website development, while an android and iOs app are usually summarized as "mobile dev". They follow the same principle though.

So what you need to do here is to construct a backend.
The flow will look like this

1. client -- http GET/Users --> server   -- *server fetches data*
2. server -- HTTP Response --> client -- *client parses data*

your server is in this  case your azure setup.
The programming language of the backend is independent of the implementation of any client. To pick a fitting language you should consider few things:

- how active is the community of the language?
- is it a commonly used language on the market?
- do you like the language at all?

good luck

Comment: How do I do that though? sorry if I sound dumb im just really confused

Comment: Check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: There's a good diagram and complete code example. It may seem overwhelming but you just need to understand the flow before you look at code.

Comment: alon, you would use a framework like Django or Flask if you want to code in Python, Spring if you want to work with Java or anyother framework for your favorite language. Read this: https://simpleprogrammer.com/what-is-back-end-development/